Strange warning running dotnet app in docker - "An issue was encountered verifying workloads. For more information, run "dotnet workload update"."
I am trying to build and run a dotnet application in docker using files from the host. My original setup was simply a docker compose block like so:
dotnet-app:
  image: dotnet/sdk:8.0
  container_name: ${APP_HOSTNAME}
  working_dir: /app/
  volumes:
    - type: bind
      source: ${PROJECT_BASE_DIR}
      target: /app      
  ports:
    - 53710:53710
    - 53711:53711
  command: dotnet run --project MyProject.App -C Debug --launch-Profile "MyProject.App"

however I noticed that when this built the project files (bin/ and obj/ directories), it was creating them as root on my filesystem which, as well as being bad practice, caused permission errors etc for tooling on the host.
So I created a dockerfile so that I could create a user in the container:
FROM dotnet/sdk:8.0

ARG HOST_GROUP_ID
ARG HOST_GROUP_NAME
ARG HOST_USER_ID
ARG HOST_USER_NAME

RUN groupadd -f -g $HOST_GROUP_ID $HOST_GROUP_NAME && \
    useradd -m -d /home/$HOST_USER_NAME -s /bin/bash -g $HOST_GROUP_ID -u $HOST_USER_ID $HOST_USER_NAME

USER "${HOST_USER_ID}:${HOST_GROUP_ID}"

and I changed the docker-compose to be:
dotnet-app:
  build: 
    dockerfile: app/Dockerfile
    args:
      HOST_USER_ID: ${HOST_USER_ID}
      HOST_USER_NAME: ${HOST_USER_NAME}
      HOST_GROUP_ID: ${HOST_GROUP_ID}
      HOST_GROUP_NAME: ${HOST_GROUP_NAME}
  container_name: ${APP_HOSTNAME}
  working_dir: /app/
  volumes:
    - type: bind
      source: ${PROJECT_BASE_DIR}
      target: /app      
  ports:
    - 53710:53710
    - 53711:53711
  command: dotnet run --project MyProject.App -C Debug --launch-Profile "MyProject.App"

this solves the issue with file permissions, they are created as my user and the application runs correctly as far as I can see, however I now get the following output line in the docker logs just before the build stage:
dotnet-app  | An issue was encountered verifying workloads. For more information, run "dotnet workload update".

connecting to the container and running dotnet workload update results in Inadequate permissions. Run the command with elevated privileges. which I assume is because I am trying to run it as the user I created, if I switch root and run that command I get
# dotnet workload update

Skipping NuGet package signature verification.
Updated advertising manifest microsoft.net.sdk.android.
Updated advertising manifest microsoft.net.sdk.ios.
Updated advertising manifest microsoft.net.sdk.maccatalyst.
Updated advertising manifest microsoft.net.sdk.macos.
Updated advertising manifest microsoft.net.sdk.maui.
Updated advertising manifest microsoft.net.sdk.tvos.
Updated advertising manifest microsoft.net.workload.mono.toolchain.current.
Updated advertising manifest microsoft.net.workload.emscripten.current.
Updated advertising manifest microsoft.net.workload.emscripten.net6.
Updated advertising manifest microsoft.net.workload.emscripten.net7.
Updated advertising manifest microsoft.net.workload.mono.toolchain.net6.
Updated advertising manifest microsoft.net.workload.mono.toolchain.net7.
Updated advertising manifest microsoft.net.sdk.aspire.
No workloads installed for this feature band. To update workloads installed with earlier SDK versions, include the --from-previous-sdk option.
Warning: Workload garbage collection failed with error: Workload version 8.0.402-baseline.24467.1 was not found..

Successfully updated workload(s): .

The message did not appear when I ran the container straight from docker compose without adding a user, which leads me to believe it's some sort of permissions thing and the app is supposed to run as root, but that has a host of problems and I can't tell if doing things this way is correct or not.
Does this message indicate something has gone wrong that I need to fix? Or is there a better way to achieve what I want to do

SDK images should be used to build app, not run it. Usually .NET apps are dockerised via multistage build and runtime image is used for running the app.

@GuruStron interesting, im not too familiar with dotnet in docker (clearly) - do you have an example of this kind of setup?

You can create a new app from the template with docker support enabled and it will do everything for you. I will try add some links later.

it's not my dotnet application it's in an existing project, so I'm just trying to dockerize it. I can certainly follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/docker-application-development-process/docker-app-development-workflow though they seem to COPY files rather than mount them, perhaps thats the way to go
